# Can destructuring assignment be used to effect a projection in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, destructuring

I'm having some trouble understanding destructuring assignment in CoffeeScript. The [documentation](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#destructuring) contains a couple of examples which together seem to imply that renaming objects during assignment can be used to project (i.e. map, translate, transform) a source object.

I am trying to project `a = [ { Id: 1, Name: 'Foo' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Bar' } ]` into `b = [ { x: 1 }, { x: 2 } ]`.  I've tried the following without success; I've clearly misunderstood something.  Can anyone explain whether this is possible?

#### My Poor Attempts That Don't Return `[ { x: 1 }, { x: 2 } ]`

```
a = [ { Id: 1, Name: 'Foo' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Bar' } ]

# Huh? This returns 1.
x = [ { Id } ] = a

# Boo! This returns [ { Id: 1, Name: 'Foo' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Bar' } ] 
y = [ { x: Id } ] = a

# Boo! This returns [ { Id: 1, Name: 'Foo' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Bar' } ]
z = [ { Id: x } ] = a
```

#### CoffeeScript's Parallel Assignment Example

```
theBait   = 1000
theSwitch = 0

[theBait, theSwitch] = [theSwitch, theBait]
```

I understand this example as implying that variables can be renamed which in this case is used to perform a swap.

#### CoffeeScript's Arbitrary Nesting Example

```
futurists =
  sculptor: "Umberto Boccioni"
  painter:  "Vladimir Burliuk"
  poet:
    name:   "F.T. Marinetti"
    address: [
      "Via Roma 42R"
      "Bellagio, Italy 22021"
    ]

{poet: {name, address: [street, city]}} = futurists
```

I understand this example as defining a selection of properties from an arbitrary object which includes assigning the elements of an array to variables.

#### Update: Using thejh's Solution to Flatten an Array of Nested Objects

```
a = [ 
  { Id: 0, Name: { First: 'George', Last: 'Clinton' } },
  { Id: 1, Name: { First: 'Bill', Last: 'Bush' } },
]

# The old way I was doing it.
old_way = _.map a, x ->
    { Id: id, Name: { First: first, Last: last } } = x
    { id, first, last }

# Using thejh's solution...
new_way = ({id, first, last} for {Id: id, Name: {First: first, Last: last}} in a)

console.log new_way
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b = ({x} for {Id: x} in a)` works:

```
coffee> a = [ { Id: 1, Name: 'Foo' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Bar' } ]
[ { Id: 1, Name: 'Foo' },
  { Id: 2, Name: 'Bar' } ]
coffee> b = ({x} for {Id: x} in a)
[ { x: 1 }, { x: 2 } ]
coffee>
```

Comment: `({x:Id} for {Id} in a)` or `({x:obj.Id} for obj in a)` comes out a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

[CoffeeScript Cookbook](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/) solves exactly the same problem as yours - solution is [map](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/mapping-arrays):

```
b = a.map (hash) -> { x: hash.id }
```

or [list comprehension](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/list-comprehensions):

```
c = ({ x: hash.id } for hash in a)
```

You can check [this fiddle online on CoffeScript homepage](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try%3aa%20%3D%20%5B%20%7B%20Id%3A%201%2C%20Name%3A%20%27Foo%27%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20Id%3A%202%2C%20Name%3A%20%27Bar%27%20%7D%20%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20a.map%20%28hash%29%20-%3E%20%7B%20x%3A%20hash.Id%20%7D%0Aconsole.info%20b%3B%0Ac%20%3D%20%28%20%7B%20x%3A%20hash.Id%20%7D%20for%20hash%20in%20a%20%29%0Aconsole.info%20c%3B%0A) (uses console.info to show results).

EDIT:

To make it destrutive just assign mapped variable `a` to itself:

```
a = a1 = [ { Id: 1, Name: 'Foo' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Bar' } ]
a = a.map (hash) -> { x: hash.Id }
console.info a;
a1 = ({ x: hash.Id } for hash in a1)
console.info a1;
```

Comment: At least in the first example, you can omit the curlies (`{}`).

Comment: @thejh Yes, but I find more readable and explicit having them (curlies) just as in second example ;)