# Mapping an array of objects to key/value pairs in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have an array of elements that I would like to apply a mapping to to convert it into key value pairs on a single object (to mimic an associative array).

The approach in [Can destructuring assignment be used to effect a projection in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157627/can-destructuring-assignment-be-used-to-effect-a-projection-in-coffeescript) does not seem to work for me as it results in a simple array instead of key/value pairs.

My language of choice is CoffeeScript or JavaScript.

An example:

```
[{name: 'a', value: 'b', other: 'c'}, {name: 'd', value: 'e', other: 'f'}]
```

is supposed to be transformed into:

```
{
  a: 'b',
  d: 'e'
}
```

One-liners are preferred. ;-)

Comment: Suggest you make an example in pure coffeescript without the jquery dependency; something that can be tested on it's own. If you then do not figure it out, maybe the rest of us can.

Comment: Marius Kjeldahl: Done. Hope this is a little clearer.

Comment: "One-liners are preferred"? Really?  # of lines !== quality.

Comment: Matt McDonald: Agreed. Still, if there is a clear one-liner I tend to use that one instead of a multi-statement solution. IMHO, the reduce approach qualifies (even though it requires a utility method).

Comment: tokland: Not yet, but I would not rule it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To fix the syntax error, you'll have to expand `{ @name: @value }` to:

```
o = {}; o[@name] = @value; o
```

You can then merge the objects with `$.extend()` and a splat (with the empty object to avoid accidentally extending jQuery):

```
$.extend {}, $(row).children('input').map(() -> o = {}; o[@name] = @value; o)...
```

Though, a simpler option would be just to use a 2-liner:

```
result = {}
$(row).children('input').each(() -> result[@name] = @value)
```

Comment: and if you REALLY must, you can throw the initialization into the callback (result?={})[@name]...

Answer (score 79):

```
var arr = [{name: 'a', value: 'b', other: 'c'}, {name: 'd', value: 'e', other: 'f'}];

var obj = arr.reduce(function ( total, current ) {
    total[ current.name ] = current.value;
    return total;
}, {});
```

Pure javascript. It's practically a one liner, and it looks hawt.

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is ES5, but isn't difficult to shim. Here's an example shim:

```
Array.prototype.reduce = function ( fun, initVal ) {
    var sum = initVal || this[ 0 ],
        i = 1, len = this.length;

    do {
        sum = fun.call( undefined, sum, this[i], i, this );
    } while ( ++i < len );

    return sum;
};
```

`arr.reduce` is a sophisticated version of `arr.map`, which is a sophisticated version of `arr.forEach`. You can do this for the same effect:

```
var obj = {};
arr.forEach(function ( val ) {
    obj[ val.name ] = val.value;
});

//and using jQuery.each
var obj = {};
$.each( arr, function ( index, val ) {
    obj[ val.name ] = val.value;
});

//latter version in coffeescript:
obj = {}
$.each( arr, (index, val) ->
    obj[ val.name ] = val.value
)
```

Comment: Are you certain that the initialization of i is correct? If there is an initVal and only a single array element, fun is never called.

Comment: @Zirak that's nice. `obj = arr.reduce ((o, item) -> o[item.name] = item.value; o), {}` in coffeescript.

Comment: @Thilo-AlexanderGinkel this is a nice dependable collection of shims: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: @Thilo-AlexanderGinkel Nice catch. Fixed and added alternatives.

Comment: Somewhat old, but you can simplify the js version to `arr.reduce(function ( total, current ) { return total[ current.name ] = current.value, total }, {})`

Answer (score 19):

```
values = {}
values[name] = value for {name, value} in arr
```

or in javascript:

```
var values = {}
arr.forEach(function(o){
    values[o.name] = o.value
})
```

Which is almost exactly what the CoffeeScript one compiles to.

Answer (score 13):

Or using plain ES6:

```js
const old = [
  {name: 'a', value: 'b', other: 'c'}, 
  {name: 'd', value: 'e', other: 'f'}
]

const transformed = Object.assign(
  {}, 
  ...old.map(({name, value}) => ({ [name]: value }))
);

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: this is a hot one liner - but can you explain this part? 

old.map(({name, value}) => ({ [name]: value }))

what is the => ( ) doing? It is returning a key value pair with a variable name, but I don't get the () or the  [] part.

Comment: It's returning a key value pair with indeed a variable key, being always the `name` value and the value being the `value` value of the old objects. So it returns `{a: 'b'}` which will be assigned to the empty object. Clear?

Comment: I spent so much time looking for what I now understand is called computed property names (`{[key]: value}`), this answer was the clue I needed to finally know what to search for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
              {name: 'a', value: 'b', other: 'c'}, 
              {name: 'd', value: 'e', other: 'f'}
            ];

arrayOfObjects.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex) {
  previousValue[currentValue.name] = currentValue.value;
  return previousValue;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 one-liner:

```
const data = [{name: 'a', value: 97}, {name: 'b', value: 98}]

data.reduce((obj, e) => ({...obj, [e.name]: e.value}), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/creating-a-dictionary-object-from-an-array

```
  myArray = [{name: 'a', value: 'b', other: 'c'}, {name: 'd', value: 'e', other: 'f'}]
  dict = {}
  dict[obj['name']] = obj['value'] for obj in myArray when obj['name']?
  console.log(JSON.stringify(dict, 0, 2));
```

This produces exactly what you want.